# Conditionally retrieve data based on a variable

Tags: sql, sas

I have the following data set:

`have`:

```
data have;
infile datalines delimiter=",";
input id $ nbtimes $ typeof $ dp $;
datalines4;
ABC,1,GROUP,A
ABC,1,GROUP,B
ABC,2,COMPANY,A
ABC,2,COMPANY,B
DEF,1,COMPANY,A
DEF,1,COMPANY,B
;;;;
run;
```

If an ID reports "Group" and "Company", I want to output the data for that entity that has `typeof= "Group"`; if an ID reports only “Company”, I want to retrieve only the data for that entity that has `typeof= "Company"`.

I want to be able to do it through `proc sql`

`want`:

| ID | nbtimes | typeof | typeof |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 1 | GROUP | A |
| ABC | 1 | GROUP | B |
| DEF | 1 | COMPANY | A |
| DEF | 1 | COMPANY | B |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SQL to create dataset with satisfied typeof, then merge it with original dataset. Based on the conditions you gave, ABC has two distinct typeof including 'GROUP', DEF has one, so here is program:

```
proc sql;
   select a.* from have a right join (
      select distinct ID,case when count(distinct typeof)>1 then 'GROUP'
      else 'COMPANY' end as typeof
      from have group by ID
    ) b
    on a.ID=b.ID and a.typeof=b.typeof;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to flag the group to decide which obs to output.  This work OK I reckon.

```
data have;
   infile datalines delimiter=",";
   input id $ nbtimes $ typeof $ dp $;
   datalines4;
ABC,1,GROUP,A
ABC,1,GROUP,B
ABC,2,COMPANY,A
ABC,2,COMPANY,B
DEF,1,COMPANY,A
DEF,1,COMPANY,B
;;;;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
data want;
   group=0;
   do _n_ = 1 by 1 until(last.id);
      set have;
      by id;
      if typeof eq 'GROUP' then group=1;
      end;
   do _n_ = 1 to _n_;
      set have;
      if group and typeof eq 'GROUP' then output;
      else if not group then output;
      end;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

[image]

Comment: I am aware you can do it using a data step. However, I want to know if it achievable through an SQL statement as I am retrieving data from a SQL pass-through